# Unexpected behavior of boolean operations in NumPy ndarray inline comparisons

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, boolean-operations

I find that attempting to perform multiple boolean comparisons on `numpy` `ndarray`s using `&`, `|`, `==`, `>=`, etc. often gives unexpected results, <strike>where the pure python order of operations seems on the surface to be violated</strike> (I was wrong about this; for example, `True | False==True` yields `True`).  What are the "rules" or things going on under the hood that explain these results? Here are a few examples:

1. Comparing a boolean `ndarray` to the results of an **elementwise** comparison on a non-boolean `ndarray`:

   ```
   In [36]: a = np.array([1,2,3])
   In [37]: b = np.array([False, True, False])
   In [38]: b & a==2 # unexpected, with no error raised!
   Out[38]: array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)

   In [39]: b & (a==2) # enclosing in parentheses resolves this
   Out[39]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
   ```
2. Elementwise `&`/`|` on boolean and non-boolean ndarrays:

   ```
   In [79]: b = np.array([True,False,True])

   In [80]: b & a # comparison is made, then array is re-cast into integers!
   Out[80]: array([1, 0, 1])
   ```
3. Finding elements of array within two values:

   ```
   In [47]: a>=2 & a<=2 # have seen this in different stackexchange threads
   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

   In [48]: (a>=2) & a<=2 # similar to behavior in In[38], but instead get *True* boolean array of
   Out[48]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

   In [49]: (a>=2) & (a<=2) # expected results
   Out[49]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
   ```
4. Logical `&`/`|` yielding results *not in* or `[0,1]` (which would be expected if a boolean result was coerced back into `int`).

   ```
   In [90]: a & 2
   Out[90]: array([0, 2, 2])
   ```

I welcome additional examples of this behavior.

Comment: In `numpy` expressions, comparisons like `<=` have a lower priority than boolean operators like `&`.  So you need ()` to ensure that the comparisons are done first.  There's no harm in using extra ().

Comment: "where the pure python order of operations seems on the surface to be violated" - why do you say that? `&` has higher precedence than `==`.

Comment: while numpy uses `&` and `|` for logic they are intended as mathematical operators which is why they have higher precedence then comparison, I'd expect `5&2==0` to do the `&` operator first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about the precedence of the `& |` binary operators vs the comparison operators:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("b & a==2")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              4 BINARY_AND
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see here that `BINARY_AND` is done first (between `b` and `a`) then the result is compared against `2` which, since it is a boolean array, is all `False`

The reason `&` and `|` have lower precedence is because they are not intended as logical operators, it represents the binary (math?) operation which numpy happens to use for logic, for example with ints I'd definitely expect the `&` to happen first:

```
if 13 & 7 == 5:
```

It is unfortunate that numpy cannot override the behaviour of the logical `and` and `or` operators since their precedence makes sense as logical operators but unfortunately they cannot be overridden so we just have to live will adding lots of brackets when doing boolean arrays.

Note that there was a [proposal to allow `and or` to be overloaded](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/)  but was [not passed](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/117510.html) since basically it would only be a small convinience for numpy while making all other strict boolean operations slower.

Comment: You're right, I was. It was a bit counter-intuitive since the LHS items are all boolean, and the RHS items are all non-boolean. This raised another issue I'm confused about though; see my new 2nd example. Can you explain why that boolean result is then re-cast into an integer array?

Comment: I suspect people often confuse the precedence of `and` and `&`.  In normal Python `and` combines the comparison, while `&` is bitwise.  In `numpy` using `and` raises a ValueError, while `&` operates elementwise.

Comment: @Luke about the casting to int, if I had to guess I'd say that since `bool` is a subclass of `int` it sees you doing `&` operation between two int arrays so it does the actual `BINARY_AND` operation elementwise then returns as integers

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen re:the PEP proposal, couldn't the python devs add the operators `&&` or `||`, for example, for logical array comparisons  with more "logical" precedence? They did that with `@`, which is solely intended for matrix multiplication (and usually, matrix multiplication in `numpy`) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @LukeDavis idk I wasn't part of that discussion.  I'd guess that having three operators that all mean "and" but have only subtle differences would be undesirable. In any case the devs for python made their choice based on the whole language and the devs for numpy are working with what they have.

Answer (score 1):

`a>=2 & a<=2` is evaluated as `a>=(2 & a)<=2`

The () part evaluates to `array([0, 0, 2], dtype=int32)`

`a>=(2 & a)` is a boolean array.  But it is part of a Python `a<x<b` expression, which internally uses short circuiting.  That is, it evaluates `a<x` and depending its value might actually skip the `<b` part.  Something like `True if a<x else x<b`.

The familiar `ValueError ambiguous` arises when a boolean array is used in a scalar Python boolean context.

Comment: So `2 & a` basically evalutes to `2*a.astype(int)`? Do you know what the reasoning behind that is? Also seems quite odd to me.

Comment: It's the `np.bitwise_and` operator.  For booleans it's same as `np.logical_and` (I think) but for integers it's a binary number operation.